# Best way to show/hide component which appears more than once in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a system to flight search. I have 4 fields (Origin, Destiny, Departure Date, Return Date). For example, when the user click in the "where" input i show a div with the airports (see image).

I have a reducer to control the state open/close of the div, like this:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  showDatePicker: 'none',
  showDestinyPicker: 'none',
  showOriginPicker: 'none',
});
```

[image]

Thats work fine for me, but now i want to allow the user add one more search, so instead of one line with fields, i can have how many the users want.

[image]

The problem is, if he clicks for example on the date picker input, the date picker div off all date picker input will appear not only the one he clicks. This happened because i just have one property to control the hide/show state.

[image]

My doubt is, what is the best way to deal with it? Keep using redux? Keep a state inside the component who hide/show and stop using redux?

Comment: Rather off-topic for stackoverflow. Anyway, I'd simply create a SearchComponent and move the state of the pickers to it. The app as a whole doesn't need to care about whether the pickers are open, so letting each search manage its own states should be fine.

Comment: yeah, you need to keep the state in the component, as of course in redux it seems you have a global state. of course you could make a global state with your open/close states in redux, but you would need to assign them also some placement id. like not only "showOriginPicker" but namespaced as e.g. sectionOne:showOriginPicker.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where/how you define those multiple searchRows.

#### You store those multiple searchRows also in redux

When you store multiple searchRows in redux, you can store also those open/close states within the redux and tie it to the row. this way your dropdowns states are within the states of the rows

```
{
  searchRows: {
    one: {
      showDatePicker: 'none',
      showDestinyPicker: 'none',
      showOriginPicker: 'none',
    },
    two: {
      showDatePicker: 'none',
      showDestinyPicker: 'none',
      showOriginPicker: 'none',
    }
  }
}
```

#### You render those multiple searchRows manually

If you render your multiple searchRows manually like so

```
   return (
      <SearchRow someProps={ ... } />
      <SearchRow someProps={ ... } />
   )
```

then you should also keep the state in each component and the SearchRow component should control the state of its dropdowns.